# ASP.WEB API call works only for json

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, fiddler, multipartform-data

I get from supprot problem on our API, one call not work Content-Type: multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8;boundary=*, but work Content-Type:application/json. How can I simulated this from fiddler? How can I convert json to be able debuging as Content-Type: multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8;boundary=*?

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<ErrorResponse> Update([FromUri]int id, [FromBody]UpdateRequest request)
```

Comment: In general, `multipart/form-data` is used when you post a form with a fileupload control.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Yes, that I know. I do not know why custormer use this, I have to fix it. And do not know how to test it / debug it

Comment: In that case show us some content from what you'll need to change.

Comment: When using Chrome you could use the Advanced Rest Client Application Extension to test your REST API

Comment: It is Http Put for entity update, so there is item id and fields for change (Name, duration, rate) Only sipmle fild string int and boolean not photos or files

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I add header to question

Answer (score 0):

Open **Fiddler**.
Go to **Composer** -> Choose **PUT** method.
In Headers write **Content-Type: multipart/form-data**
In URL write **?id=5**
In Request body write your **UpdateRequest** **class structure**

Here is example:

[image]